# Is it safe to sign in to Google with password from desktop app like BlueStacks?

Tags: passwords, google, appsec

[BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) is an android simulator for desktop. After installation it will ask you to login with your Google account to download and install android app from play-store.

My question is "Is it safe to sign in to Google account with password from a desktop app"?

Comment: If your desktop is infected with malware - it isn't. If you don't trust Google or BlueStacks - it isn't.

Comment: Short answer: NO. Software is also not open source /subject to expert scrutiny and nobody knows how your data is being used. Though Bluestacks claims it is safe with them but one never knows. Even though their intentions may be good, but nobody else can vouch for the methods they have used to secure your data.

Alternatives: are change your password after using Bluestacks (painful) or create a Gmail account just for use in Bluestacks.

Answer (score 2):

Anything you type your password into has the theoretical capability to mis-use it. That includes everything you're already using your google account with, such as your PC and smartphone.

To answer your question you would need to make a risk assessment of all the things that could go wrong, and work out what to do about it.

We can't really do that for you, because we don't know what sort of information you might put through this app or have protected by your Google password; and we don't know what your risk tolerance is.

Comment: BTW, looking quickly at their Web site, I'd say they're probably legit and fairly well established (good) and that their Ts & Cs give them a lot of leeway to slurp up your data (bad).